# One submit button to send form data to one PHP destination OR another

Tags: php, html

I' new to HTML and PHP and was wondering if anyone out there could help me with a question...  I'm trying to code a form that submits a selection from one  menu OR another and, depending on which is chosen sends the data to one of two different PHP pages.

```
    <form id="form1" method="post" action="">
                <label for="SubjectID">Text Books by Subject</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                  <select "name="SubjectID" id="SubjectID">
                    <?php do {  ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row_rsSubject['SubjectID']?>"><?php echo $row_rsSubject['SubjectName']?></option>
                    <?php } while ($row_rsSubject = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsSubject));
                         $rows = mysql_num_rows($rsSubject);
                        if($rows > 0) {
                            mysql_data_seek($rsSubject, 0);
                            $row_rsSubject = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsSubject);
                        } ?>
                  </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                &mdash;&mdash;&mdash; OR &mdash;&mdash;&mdash;
            </p>
            <p>
                  <select name="CourseID" id="CourseID">
                    <?php do {  ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row_rsCourse['CourseID']?>"><?php echo $row_rsCourse['CourseID']?></option>
                    <?php } while ($row_rsCourse = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCourse));
                        $rows = mysql_num_rows($rsCourse);
                        if($rows > 0) {
                            mysql_data_seek($rsCourse, 0);
                            $row_rsCourse = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCourse);
                        } ?>
                  </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                  <label for="CourseID">Text Books by Course</label>
             </form>
```

So, the action should be (depending on which menu the user selects from) that the form submits to either subject.php or course.php, and I can't figure out how to do that with a single submit button.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: you need javascript not php

Answer (score 1):

first set onchange event to select:

```
<select name="CourseID" id="CourseID" onchange='myFunc(this)'>
```

Then:

```
<script>
    function myFunc(element){
      // set the form action depends on option chosen
      // element.setAttribute('action', 'yourPageLink' );
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could update the `action` attribute with javascript when the user changes his selection, directing him to the relevant page.

Otherwise, why not submit to a single function and depending on the users selection call the relevant function?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I would use jquery's $.post to do this. To the best of my knowledge you can't really do that with straight html, and php is executed before the page loads so that's no help. With JQuery you could set an action to the button to call a function. Then your function could check the value of the select and pass the proper url to the $.post function.

You can read about that particular jquery function here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

If you're not familiar with JQuery it's really easy to use with just a bit of reading if you're good with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a radio button in the form whose posted form value is processed by a central PHP form handler? That way, depending on what is entered on the radio button, you can process the request as necessary.

This might not be the answer you are looking for, but I am not clear if you want the user to be able to alter the destination or what.

Comment: This could also be a select drop down for the record!